# mod_rewrite not working with query string without file extension

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite **user/John-Doe** to **user?name=John-Doe** with `mod_rewrite` in `.htaccess`. I have the **.htaccess** in the same directory with the file I'm rewriting/redirecting. This is the code in the **htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^user/(\w+)/?$ user?name=$1
```

Now I do not receive any data from $_GET['name'] and var_dump($_GET) is empty.

Comment: `\w` does not match hyphens, you need `[\w-]`

Comment: Do you have any other rules too in your file or only this one? Please confirm once.

Comment: Is `user` a script capable to run PHP? Shouldn't that be `user.php?name=$1`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks it worked on the local serve but once I uploaded it to my webhosting each got 404 error

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 there are other rules but not in this file.

Comment: @brombeer yes it is a php script

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture more characters with `[\w-]+`
Also, you are point the request to `user?name=$1` that should be `user.php?name=$1`?

`.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> # Check if mod_rewrite if avaible
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteRule ^user/([\w-]+)/?$ user.php?name=$1
</IfModule>
```

`user.php`

```php
<?php
var_dump($_GET);
```

```
array(1) { ["name"]=> string(8) "John-Doe" }
```

Test example

https://regex101.com/r/up32vA/1

---

Also check if `mod_rewrite` is enabled in your server, a easy way is putting this in index.php

```
print_r( apache_get_modules() );
```